# IQueryable Extensions working on expression for collection property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, properties, linq-expressions

Followup to [Repository searching code duplication](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146449/repository-searching-code-duplication)

My goal currently is to make the current implementation of my repository's IQueryable filtering less duplicative. First, I looked into passing expressions around to target properties generically so that I can create reusable methods in a new extensions class I created:

```
internal static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByAtLeast<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) >= 0);
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByAtMost<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) <= 0);
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByContains<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, string value, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> property)
    {
        return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).Contains(value));
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByExact<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).Equals(value));
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByGreaterThan<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) > 0);
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByGuids<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, Filter<TModel> filter)
        where TModel : PocoBase
    {
        return query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByLessThan<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) < 0);
    }

    internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByNumericComparator<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, NumericSearchComparators comparator, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<TModel, TPropertyType>> property)
        where TPropertyType : IComparable
    {
        switch (comparator)
        {
            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThan:
                return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) > 0);

            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) >= 0);

            case NumericSearchComparators.EqualTo:
                return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) == 0);

            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThan:
                return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) < 0);

            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                return query.Where(x => property.Compile().Invoke(x).CompareTo(value) <= 0);

            default:
                return query;
        }
    }

    //internal static IQueryable<TModel> FilterByAnyContaining<TModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, TPropertyType value, Expression<Func<ICollection<TModel>, ICollection<TPropertyType>, TPropertyType>> property)
    //{
    //    return query.Where(x => value == null || property.Compile().Invoke(x).Contains(value));
    //}
}
```

The commented out method in that class is one that I'm currently stuck on. I would like to extract out code like this:

```
internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQueryByAdmin(IQueryable<Company> query, ContactFilter filter)
{
    query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.CellNumber) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Admin.CellNumber.Contains(filter.CellNumber)));
    query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Clients.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.AdminContactId)));
    return query;
}

internal static IQueryable<Product> FilterProductQuery(IQueryable<Product> query, DiscountFilter filter)
{
    if (filter.Amount != null && filter.AmountComparator != null)
    {
        switch (filter.AmountComparator.Value)
        {
            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThan:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount > filter.Amount));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount >= filter.Amount));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.EqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount == filter.Amount));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThan:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount < filter.Amount));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount <= filter.Amount));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (filter.Threshold != null && filter.ThresholdComparator != null)
    {
        switch (filter.ThresholdComparator.Value)
        {
            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThan:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold > filter.Threshold.Value));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold >= filter.Threshold.Value));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.EqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold == filter.Threshold.Value));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThan:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold < filter.Threshold.Value));
                break;
            case NumericSearchComparators.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold <= filter.Threshold.Value));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    query = query.Where(x => filter.IsPercent == null || x.Discounts.Any(y => y.IsPercent == filter.IsPercent.Value));
    return query;
}
```

...into additional extension methods that are as generic as possible.

The part where I'm struggling to wrap my head around is how to set up these `Expressions` and/or `Expression<Func<>>`s when I get to sending in a collection of a second model type and I want to target a property on that secondary model.

I'm thinking of the above examples in this sense - **"I need a query which will return all Products whose collections of Discounts contains at least one match for this value on this property"**

The full set of code I'm currently using in the `Filterer` class is:

```
internal static class RepositoryQueryFilterer
{
    internal static IQueryable<Account> FilterAccountQuery(IQueryable<Account> query, AccountFilter filter)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Notes) ? query.FilterByContains(filter.Notes, x => x.Notes) : query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Client> FilterClientQuery(IQueryable<Client> query, ClientFilter filter)
    {
        return filter != null ? FilterClientQueryFilters(query, filter) : query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Client> FilterClientQueryByAccountSearch(IQueryable<Client> query, AccountFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Notes, x => x.Account.Notes);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Client> FilterClientQueryByAdminSeach(IQueryable<Client> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.CellNumber, x => x.Admin.CellNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Email, x => x.Admin.Email);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.OfficeNumber, x => x.Admin.OfficeNumber);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.AdminContactId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Client> FilterClientQueryByPrimaryContactSeach(IQueryable<Client> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Email, x => x.PrimaryContact.Email);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.CellNumber, x => x.PrimaryContact.CellNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.OfficeNumber, x => x.PrimaryContact.OfficeNumber);
        query = query.Where(x => filter.ItemGuids != null && filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.PrimaryContactId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQuery(IQueryable<Company> query, CompanyFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterCompanyQuery(query, filter.ClientFilter);
        query = FilterCompanyQuery(query, filter.LocationFilter);
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name) || x.Name.Contains(filter.Name));
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQuery(IQueryable<Company> query, ClientFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterCompanyQuery(query, filter.AccountFilter);
        query = FilterCompanyQueryByAdmin(query, filter.AdminFilter);
        query = FilterCompanyQueryByPrimaryContact(query, filter.PrimaryContactFilter);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Clients.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.Id)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQuery(IQueryable<Company> query, AccountFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Notes) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Account.Notes.Contains(filter.Notes)));
        query = query.Where(x => filter.ItemGuids != null && filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Clients.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.AccountId)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQuery(IQueryable<Company> query, LocationFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Description) || x.Locations.Any(y => y.Description.Contains(filter.Description)));
        query = //query.FilterByAnyContaining(filter.Label, x => x.Locations.Any(y => y.Label))
            query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Label) || x.Locations.Any(y => y.Label.Contains(filter.Label)));
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Locations.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.Id)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQueryByAdmin(IQueryable<Company> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.CellNumber) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Admin.CellNumber.Contains(filter.CellNumber)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.OfficeNumber) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Admin.OfficeNumber.Contains(filter.OfficeNumber)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Email) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Admin.Email.Contains(filter.Email)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.Admin.Name.Contains(filter.Name)));
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Clients.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.AdminContactId)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Company> FilterCompanyQueryByPrimaryContact(IQueryable<Company> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.CellNumber) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.PrimaryContact.CellNumber.Contains(filter.CellNumber)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.OfficeNumber) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.PrimaryContact.OfficeNumber.Contains(filter.OfficeNumber)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Email) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.PrimaryContact.Email.Contains(filter.Email)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name) || x.Clients.Any(y => y.PrimaryContact.Name.Contains(filter.Name)));
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Clients.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.PrimaryContactId)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQuery(IQueryable<Contact> query, ClientFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.AccountFilter);
        query = FilterContactQueryByAdmin(query, filter.AdminFilter);
        query = FilterContactQueryByPrimaryContact(query, filter.PrimaryContactFilter);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.ClientId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQuery(IQueryable<Contact> query, CompanyFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.LocationFilter);
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.ClientFilter);
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.LocationFilter);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Name);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQuery(IQueryable<Contact> query, AccountFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Notes, x => x.Client.Account.Notes);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Client.AccountId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQuery(IQueryable<Contact> query, LocationFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Description) || x.Company.Locations.Any(y => y.Description.Contains(filter.Description)));
        query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Label) || x.Company.Locations.Any(y => y.Label.Contains(filter.Label)));
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || x.Company.Locations.Any(y => filter.ItemGuids.Contains(y.Id)));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQuery(IQueryable<Contact> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.ClientFilter);
        query = FilterContactQuery(query, filter.CompanyFilter);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.CellNumber, x => x.CellNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.OfficeNumber, x => x.OfficeNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Email, x => x.Email);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Name);
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQueryByAdmin(IQueryable<Contact> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.CellNumber, x => x.Client.Admin.CellNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.OfficeNumber, x => x.Client.Admin.OfficeNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Email, x => x.Client.Admin.Email);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Client.Admin.Name);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Client.AdminContactId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Contact> FilterContactQueryByPrimaryContact(IQueryable<Contact> query, ContactFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.CellNumber, x => x.Client.PrimaryContact.CellNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.OfficeNumber, x => x.Client.PrimaryContact.OfficeNumber);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Email, x => x.Client.PrimaryContact.Email);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Client.PrimaryContact.Name);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Client.PrimaryContactId));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Discount> FilterDiscountQuery(DiscountFilter filter, IQueryable<Discount> query)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterDiscountQuery(filter.ProductFilter, query);
        query = query.Where(x => filter.IsPercent == null || x.IsPercent == filter.IsPercent.Value);
        query = filter.Amount != null && filter.AmountComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.AmountComparator.Value, filter.Amount.Value, x => x.Amount)
            : query;
        query = filter.Threshold != null && filter.ThresholdComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.ThresholdComparator.Value, filter.Threshold.Value, x => x.Threshold)
            : query;
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Discount> FilterDiscountQuery(ProductFilter filter, IQueryable<Discount> query)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Title, x => x.Product.Title);
        query = filter.Price != null && filter.PriceComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.PriceComparator.Value, filter.Price.Value, x => x.Product.Price)
            : query;
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<CompanyLocation> FilterLocationQuery(IQueryable<CompanyLocation> query, LocationFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterLocationQuery(query, filter.CompanyFilter);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Description, x => x.Description);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Label, x => x.Label);
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<CompanyLocation> FilterLocationQuery(IQueryable<CompanyLocation> query, CompanyFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Company.Name);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Order> FilterOrderQuery(IQueryable<Order> query, OrderFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = FilterOrderQuery(query, filter.CompanyFilter);
        query = FilterOrderQuery(query, filter.ProductFilter);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Notes, x => x.Notes);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.PositionsOfInterest.Any() || x.PositionsOfInterest.Any(y => filter.PositionsOfInterest.Contains(y)));
        query = filter.OrderStatus != null && filter.OrderStatus.Any()
                    ? query.Where(x => filter.OrderStatus.Contains(x.Status))
                    : query;
        query = filter.Quantity != null && filter.QuantityComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.QuantityComparator.Value, filter.Quantity.Value, x => x.Quantity)
            : query;
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        if (filter.Completed != null && filter.CompletedComparator != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Status == OrderStatus.Completed);
            switch (filter.CompletedComparator.Value)
            {
                case DateTimeSearchComparators.After:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Completed > filter.Completed.Value);
                    break;
                case DateTimeSearchComparators.Before:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Completed < filter.Completed.Value);
                    break;
                case DateTimeSearchComparators.DayOf:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Completed.Value.DayOfYear == filter.Completed.Value.DayOfYear);
                    break;
                case DateTimeSearchComparators.HourOf:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Completed.Value.Hour == filter.Completed.Value.Hour);
                    break;
                case DateTimeSearchComparators.Exactly:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Completed.Value == filter.Completed.Value);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Order> FilterOrderQuery(IQueryable<Order> query, CompanyFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Name, x => x.Company.Name);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Order> FilterOrderQuery(IQueryable<Order> query, ProductFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Title, x => x.Product.Title);
        query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
        query = filter.Price != null && filter.PriceComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.PriceComparator.Value, filter.Price.Value, x => x.Product.Price)
            : query;
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Product> FilterProductQuery(IQueryable<Product> query, ProductFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        FilterProductQuery(query, filter.DiscountFilter);
        query = query.FilterByContains(filter.Title, x => x.Title);
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        query = filter.Price != null && filter.PriceComparator != null
            ? query.FilterByNumericComparator(filter.PriceComparator.Value, filter.Price.Value, x => x.Price)
            : query;
        return query;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<Product> FilterProductQuery(IQueryable<Product> query, DiscountFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null) return query;
        if (filter.Amount != null && filter.AmountComparator != null)
        {
            switch (filter.AmountComparator.Value)
            {
                case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThan:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount > filter.Amount));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount >= filter.Amount));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.EqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount == filter.Amount));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.LessThan:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount < filter.Amount));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Amount <= filter.Amount));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (filter.Threshold != null && filter.ThresholdComparator != null)
        {
            switch (filter.ThresholdComparator.Value)
            {
                case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThan:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold > filter.Threshold.Value));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold >= filter.Threshold.Value));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.EqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold == filter.Threshold.Value));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.LessThan:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold < filter.Threshold.Value));
                    break;
                case NumericSearchComparators.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Discounts.Any(y => y.Threshold <= filter.Threshold.Value));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        query = query.Where(x => filter.IsPercent == null || x.Discounts.Any(y => y.IsPercent == filter.IsPercent.Value));
        return query;
    }

    private static IQueryable<Client> FilterClientQueryFilters(IQueryable<Client> query, ClientFilter filter)
    {
        query = FilterClientQueryByAccountSearch(query, filter.AccountFilter);
        query = FilterClientQueryByAdminSeach(query, filter.AdminFilter);
        query = FilterClientQueryByPrimaryContactSeach(query, filter.PrimaryContactFilter);
        query = query.FilterByGuids(filter);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked out the typings and expressions required to extract the common logic that was being duplicated in numerous places. Lines like this:

```
return query.Where(x => x.Clients.Any(y => y.Account.Notes.Contains(filter.Notes);
```

...can be expressed generically (well, this particular case requires that hardcoded 'string' typing, not sure if there's a way around that) as this:

```
internal static IQueryable<TContainerModel> FilterByAnyContaining<TContainerModel, TCollectionModel>(this IQueryable<TContainerModel> query, string value, Expression<Func<TContainerModel, ICollection<TCollectionModel>>> collection, Expression<Func<TCollectionModel, string>> property)
{
    return query.Where(x => value == null || collection.Compile().Invoke(x).Any(y => property.Compile().Invoke(y).Contains(value)));
}
```

With that worked out finally, I think the only other thing I need is a somewhat similar method that works with a collection of items and a single value to find:

```
internal static IQueryable<TContainerModel> FilterByAnyContaining<TContainerModel, TPropertyType>(this IQueryable<TContainerModel> query, ICollection<TPropertyType> collection, Expression<Func<TContainerModel, TPropertyType>> property)
{
    return query.Where(x => !collection.Any() || !collection.Contains(property.Compile().Invoke(x)));
}
```

Which allows me to convert lines like this:

```
query = query.Where(x => !filter.ItemGuids.Any() || filter.ItemGuids.Contains(x.Id));
```

To this:

```
query = query.FilterByAnyContaining(filter.ItemGuids, x => x.Id);
```

Everything else I see currently I think I can apply the Rule of Three to and just leave it be a single use case.

This is certainly a case where coming back to the problem a day later helped make wrapping my mind around the problem I faced easier.  Hopefully this helps somebody else!